# Why That Code Returns 'None' (Tuples in List)

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
posts = []
rows = [('02.02', 'title2', 'text2', 15, 1), ('01.02', 'title', 'text', 16, 1)]
rows = rows.sort(key=lambda x:x[3])
for i in range(2):
     posts.append(rows[i])
print(posts)
```

Why that code returns `None` and how can I fix it?

Comment: As a bit of background as to why `.sort()` works ‘in-place’, do a bit of research on *mutable* vs. *immutable* objects in Python; of which a `list` is mutable.

Comment: Beside the point, but you don't need that for-loop, just `posts.extend(rows[:2])`, or even get rid of `posts = []` and just do `posts = rows[:2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
rows = rows.sort(key=lambda x:x[3])
```

You want:

```
rows.sort(key=lambda x:x[3])
```

Because the `.sort()` will automatically update `rows` without the need to reassign like so:

```
posts = []
rows = [('02.02', 'title2', 'text2', 15, 1), ('01.02', 'title', 'text', 16, 1)]
rows.sort(key=lambda x:x[3]) #notice the change here
for i in range(2):
     posts.append(rows[i])
print(posts)
```

Output:

```
[('02.02', 'title2', 'text2', 15, 1), ('01.02', 'title', 'text', 16, 1)]
```

The `.sort()` function updates rows, but returns `None`.

Comment: uh... that's true. thanks for helping me. :)